# How to set posts per page using WP_Query()

Tags: query-posts, wp-query

I'm trying to set the number of posts_per_page dynamically using my own variable. This code works fine:

```
query_posts( $query_string  . "&posts_per_page=" . $myvar )
// then display the loop using get_template_part( 'loop' );
```

That works fine, but I would like to know how to do it using $wp_query instead of query_posts. However, this does not work:

```
$wp_query->set('posts_per_page', $myvar)
// then display the loop using get_template_part( 'loop' );
```

That has no effect on the number of posts displayed. Am I using the set method incorrectly, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`query_posts` will do the query again (destroy current wp_query and create a new one and then doing the query with the parameters you pass to it)

To get the same behaviour after setting the new parameter with `set_var` you need to query the database again using something like this

```
 $wp_query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
 $wp_query->query($wp_query->query_vars);
```

Answer (score 2):

when you call `query_posts` with a modified query in your template, you're actually running another query and discarding the original. trying to set a query var in your template doesn't work because the original query has already happened. to use `$wp_query->set()` you have to hook in *before* the database is queried, for example on `pre_get_posts`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use `$wp_query->set()` at all?

Can't you just use:

```
<?php
$my_custom_query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $myvar
);
$my_custom_query = new WP_Query( $my_custom_query_args );
?>
```

Comment: Aren't you destroying all other query arguments that way? The `->set()` method should keep the rest of the arguments the same, just change `post_per_page`. Or am I misreading this?

Answer (score -1):

You may use

```
$wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 25
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please be a bit more verbose with your answers and explain the **why this answer helps**-part as well? Else answers get automatically flagged as _low quality_ by the community bot. Thanks. Hint: You will have to at least wrap your call in a callback function attached to a filter :)